# Why hyphenation is not working in documnent?

Tags: parallel, parallel-texts, hyphenat

I am trying to write a parallel texts, right column text as the translation of the left column to achieve this i am using `parallel` package, i have observed that `hyphenat` package is not working i want text to break automatically into lines. Till now i have tried so far as shown below

```
  \documentclass[twoside,letterpaper]{book}
  \usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{hyphenat}
  \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
  \usepackage{lettrine}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \usepackage{fixltx2e}

  \newcommand{\jChapter}[1]{\par\bigskip\lettrine{{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}{}\markboth{\chaplabel\ #1:1}{\chaplabel\ #1:1}\renewcommand{\jnumChapters}{#1}}

  \newcommand{\jverseFormat}[1]{#1}
  \newcommand{\jChapterNumFormat}[1]{\textcolor{cyan}{\textbf{#1}}}

  \newcommand{\jverse}[3]{\noindent{\jChapterNumFormat{#1}\markboth{\chaplabel\ \jnumChapters :#1}{\chaplabel\ \jnumChapters :#1}} #2{\jverseFormat{#3}}\par\smallskip\renewcommand{\jnumVerses}{#1}}

  \newcommand{\jBracketWord}[1]{\emph{#1}}

  \newcommand{\jParaSymbol}[0]{{}}

  \raggedright

  \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.0pt}

  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
  \fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
  \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
  \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}

  \newcommand{\chaplabel}{}
  \newcommand{\jnumChapters}{0}
  \newcommand{\jnumVerses}{0}
  \usepackage{parallel}




  \begin{document}
  \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\emph{\alph{footnote}}}
  \frontmatter

  \title{The Holy Bible}
  \date{}
  \author{}
  \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
  \maketitle

  %\tableofcontents
  \mainmatter

  \part*{The Old Testament}
  \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.0pt}
  \renewcommand{\jnumChapters}{0}
  \chapter{Kecheng}
  \renewcommand{\chaplabel}{Kecheng}
  \hfill{\textbf{KEPACHINI}}\hfill~\\
  Kecheng amen kepudamke `atiri'. Laso aloh pirthe-sining, monit akhei keplang, pap kecheng lapen pirthe athak kesung kechechaknang alam lapen monit akhei aphan Arnam kelang alamsi thanlo. Kecheng aloh ingkung-hini thakme. 1. Angdengpi 1-11 pirthe kethip lapen kechengsi monit akhei aphurkimo. Ladak Adam lapen Iv alam, Kein lapen Abel, Noah lapen langthepi, lapen Bebilon ahemchardom alam heihei toklo.

  2. Angdengpi 12-50 Israel kechengsi aphusar atum aphurkimo. Kechengsi ke Abraham, alangli akekroithip lapen Arnam aphan alangli kekroi alam anong chethang-o. Laso aphi alangli sopo Isaak atomo lapen asupo Jakob (Israel pu ta pu), lapen Jakob asopo bangkrehini Israel akhei keseng atum-lo. Jasemet ke asopomar atum angbong inut abang Joseph aphansi pudam muchot lo, lapen Jakob aphan lapen alangli kaprek asomar, halatum ahemtun heihei pen pen Ijip adet kepadodamjisi kevan alam heihei si tok-lo.

  Laso aloh rat atum atomoheihei kethan un ahut, lake kechengsi ke isi Arnam kopisi klemtangloma laso alakha lo. La kecheng ke Arnam si pirthe-sining pinchonglo pu puthip-lo, lapen Arnam arat-aso aphan chelangver po pu kechak alam pen la pajut-lo. Loh apharsoding kethenei abangphu ke Arnam, Alangli ingsai lapen kechokche keklem abangphan aduk-pilo, jalo, lapen Alangli rat aphan rap-lo, lapen halatum phurkimo padolo. Laso hako aloh ketok ke isi kekroithip arat atomosi tok-pen bilo, lapen halaso akekroithip kebi pen keparengji aphansi rap-dunlo. Kecheng Aloh ketok lake Khristo Aphrang 1446-1406 aningkan malom, lapen laso aloh Moses-si tok-lo.\\\vspace{2mm}

  \hrule
  \vspace{10mm}

  \begin{Parallel}{9.1cm}{9.1cm}
  \ParallelLText{\bf\large\textit{Kethip-ketheng Atomo}}
  \ParallelRText{\bf\large\textit{The Story of Creation}}
  \ParallelPar
  \ParallelLText{\jverse{1}{}{Kechengsi, Arnam sining-heihei lapen pirthe kepinchong ahut,}}
  \ParallelRText{\jverse{1}{}{In the beginning, when God created the universe,}}
  \ParallelPar
  \ParallelLText{\jverse{2}{}{pirthe arje avelang lapen thangnatta ave, lapen lang-lom athak kangtingsi dolang; lapen Arnam Akarjong\footnotemark lang-heihei athak damlo.}}
  \ParallelRText{\jverse{2}{}{the earth was formless and desolate. The raging ocean that covered everything was engulfed in total darkness, and the Spirit of God was moving over the water.}}
  \footnotetext{Arnam akarjong mate Arnam ajakong; mate Arnam pen tomon kejap; mate kepherememe atomon Arnam pen kejap}
  \ParallelPar
  \ParallelLText{\jverse{3}{}{Lapen Arnam pulo, ``kethe-ang padonang;'' lapen  the-angdang-lo.}}
  \ParallelRText{\jverse{3}{}{Then God commanded, ``Let there be light'' and light appeared.}}
  \ParallelPar
  \ParallelLText{\jverse{4}{}{Lapen Arnam thek-long-lo kethe-ang mesen; lapen Arnam kethe-ang pen kangting thak-lo.}}
  \ParallelRText{\jverse{4}{}{God was pleased with what he saw. Then he separated the light from the darkness,}}
  \ParallelPar
  \ParallelLText{\jverse{5}{}{Kethe-ang aphan Anerlo pusi Arnam irlo, lapen kangting aphan Ajo pusi irlo. Lapen aningve lapen adap nangdolo, la kecheng arni lo.}}
  \ParallelRText{\jverse{5}{}{and he named the light ``Day'' and the darkness ``Night.'' Evening passed and morning came—that was the first day.}}
  \ParallelPar
  \ParallelLText{\jverse{6}{}{Anke Arnam pulo, ``Lang-heihei angbong sining-inghun angpong padonang, lapen lang-heihei pen lang-heihei thakdak lonang.''}}
  \ParallelRText{\jverse{6}{}{Then God commanded, ``Let there be a dome to divide the water and to keep it in two separate places''—and it was done.}}
  \ParallelPar
  \ParallelLText{\jverse{7}{}{Lapen Arnam sining-inghun angpong selamsi la aber kedo alang-heihei lapen la athak kedo alang-heihei pen thakdak-lo. Lasi la plang-lo.}}
  \ParallelRText{\jverse{7}{}{So God made a dome, and it separated the water under it from the water above it.}}
  \ParallelPar
  \ParallelLText{\jverse{8}{}{Lapen Arnam angpong aphan ``Sining-inghun'' pusi irlo. Ningve apor jut si adap nangtheang-lo, la ke hini arnilo.}}
  \ParallelRText{\jverse{8}{}{He named the dome ``Sky.'' Evening passed and morning came—that was the second day.}}
  \ParallelPar
  \ParallelLText{\jverse{9}{}{Anke Arnam pulo, ``sining-heihei kedo aber alang-heihei an elong adim padopet lonang, lapen kekrengdang alongle nangpaklang lonang.'' Lapen la plang-lo.}}
  \ParallelRText{\jverse{9}{}{Then God commanded, ``Let the water below the sky come together in one place, so that the land will appear''—and it was done.}}
  \ParallelPar
  \end{Parallel}
  \end{document}
```

Here is the output of the above code
[image]

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity, what language is used in the left-hand column?

Comment: left-hand column text is in Karbi language and those text is in english only @Mico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the tag `\raggedright` then, it will work